# ORM Design with foreign keys in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, oop

I am new to OOP in PHP so I have a "basic" question.
I have two business classes called 'customer' and 'orders'

```
class Customer    //corresponding to MySQL table 'customers'
protected $customerNo;
protected $customerName;
//remaining customer details......

class Orders         //corresponding to MYSQL table 'orders'
protected $orderNo;
protected $customerNo;   //foreign key from above class/table 
//remaining order details.....
```

Should the Orders class load the customer object when its instantiated so the following can be done?

```
$objOrder = new Orders($orderNo);
$objOrder->objCustomer->someCustomerClassMethod();
```

Basically, if a table has one or more foreign keys which basically "point" to another business class object, should those (foreign key related) objects be instantiated along with the object in question?

Comment: No good practice is to only have the id of the customer in your order. Just reflect the reality.

Comment: I would say the other way around makes more sense, ie a customer has orders. an order does not have customers. As for instantiating the object inside the other is debatable. You might find this video on dependency injection a good  watch, http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IKD2-MAkXyQ

Answer (score 0):

I would not do this using constructor, simply because it is missleading and unclear.

Constructor in a **businees class** means creation of a NEW BUSINESS OBJECT. Technically you create a PHP object here, but logically you should think on a business level. On a business level, the operation you want to do is a simple **query**, aimed to get a business object with certain characteristics (in this case, with a specified ID).

So, instead of:

> $objOrder = new Orders($orderNo);

I would simply have:

> $objOrder = Orders::get($orderNo);

get is a static method in Orders class, kind of a service, logically a clear and natural solution to your need. It is defined this way:

```
class Orders {
    public static function get(id) {
       // use this id to retrieve the corresponding object - order

       return order;    
    }

    // other stuff here
}
```

Use constructors only if you really want to create a new business object (e.g. to connecto to the DB, create a new instance).